# Jquery: how to call a callback function on ALL ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

is there a way to create in jquery a callback function that is automatically called before ALL ajax request?

I need it to check if the session still active but dont want to add it to all 100+ ajax calls i already havecoded on my site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could us the [`.ajaxSetup()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) method which allows you to register a global `beforeSend` callback that will be executed before each AJAX call:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Comment: .ajaxStart() will only trigger if there is no other Ajax request currently running. You should use ajaxSetup() instead to set a beforeSend option for all future jQuery Ajax requests.

Comment: @devnull69, correct, I have just realized that by reading it in the documentation and updated my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @charles, there's `complete`, `success`, `error` depending on what exactly you need.

Answer (score 2):

Use .ajaxSetup() like this

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {
        // jqXHR is a reference to the jQuery XMLHttpRequest object
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your condition is to run the jquery callback, but you can search

```
               .trigger() function
```

maybe

```
              $.ajax({
                $(selector).trigger()
              $("selector").ajaxComplete(function(){
                });

               });
```